# Unable to get the activity view behind the dialogue

Tags: android, view

I have an activity over which contains imageview added dynamically on clicking a button. Over the activity i am inflating a dialogue box on click of the dynamically added image . Inside the dialog box i have a button to delete that image which is popping up that dialog .

My problem is how to access that imageview instance which is behind the dialog , so that i could delete it .

//Popping up the dialog on click of the imageview
imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            customPotraitDialog = new CustomPotraitDialog(potrait);
            customPotraitDialog.show();  

//This i am doing on click of the button inside the dialog
   dismiss();
   View parent = (View) v.getParent();
   RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout) parent.findViewById(R.layout.potrait);
   deleteFromPotrait(view);
```

Potrait is my layout of the from where the dialog is popping up. It returning the view as null.

Comment: the on click method is returning the ImageView, and making the imageView final you have access to it in the onClick method.

Answer (score 0):

Pass instance of your activity to the dialog then **onClick()** **deleteFromPotrait(view)** method that is **public**  in your activity like the following:

calling dialog

```
customPotraitDialog = new CustomPotraitDialog(potrait, context);
```

inside your dialog constructor:

```
public CustomPotraitDialog(potrait, context)
{
  this.potrait = potrait;
  this.context = context;

}
```

onClick():

```
((YourActivityName) context).deleteFromPotrait(view);
```